# Decoupling K3S and containerd

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, containerd

I am trying to run k3s on a pre-installed cointainerd on the node.
My goal in general is that when k3s is stopped, containerd will keep running.

It is also preferable that k3s will use the same containerd runtime as mentioned above.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a flag `--container-runtime-endpoint` which can be passed with the socket of your pre-installed containerd while initializing the k3s server/agent.

How to: [agent-runtime-flags](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/install-options/server-config/#agent-runtime)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).